# What is the equivalent of Select into in Google bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to write a SQL Command to insert some data from one table to a new table without any insert statement in bigquery but I cannot find a way to do it. (something similar to select into)

Here is the table:

```
create table database1.table1 
(
    pdesc string,
    num int64
);
```

And here is the insert statement. I also tried the select into but it is not supported in bigquery.

```
insert into database1.table1
    select column1, count(column2) as num
    from database1.table2
    group by column1;
```

Above is a possible way to insert. but I am looking for a way that I do not need to use any select statement. I am looking for something similar to 'select into' statement.

I am thinking of declaring variables and then somehow feed the data into the tables but do not know how.

Comment: what is wrong with `insert into`?

Comment: there is no issue. but the task should be done without insert and I stock in it. I am trying to declare variables and then somehow to do this but I cannot think about a way

Comment: why without? that is the question! what is wrong with `insert`?! it is hard to help when it is not understood why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a Google employee.  However - I understand the reasoning for not supporting creating a copy of a table (or query) from the console.

The challenge is that each table needs to be created must have a number of features defined such as associated project and expiry time.

Looking through the documentation (briefly) - it is worth exploring using **bq** utility - specifically the **cp** command -

Explore the following operations :

- cache the query results to a temporary table
- get the name of said temporary table
- pass to a copy table command perhaps?

Other methods are described in the google cloud doco https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#copy-table